# Using multiple native libraries with different ABI Android

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am having troubling using multiple native libraries. I have a lib1 with only **armeabi** version where as the other library (lib2) has other EBI versions too like **armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86** . The problem is that, if I use only the ameabi for both the libraries, the app works. But if I use all the versions along with only armeabi version of lib1, then the app crashes because its trying to load the armeabi-v7a version of lib1 also which is not present.

This is the error which I am getting, in case it helps:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/services.singularity.home-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/services.singularity.home-2/lib/arm, /data/app/services.singularity.home-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libSDL.so"
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
```